# Laravel middleware doesn't work

Tags: php, laravel, middleware

I created my middleware, registered it in Kernel.php (middlewareGroups and in routeMiddleware arrays) but it does nothing.

Kernel.php/middlewareGroups

```
'CheckAdmin' => [
    \App\Http\Middleware\CheckUserIfAdmin::class,
],
```

Kernel.php/routeMiddleware

```
'CheckAdmin' => \App\Http\Middleware\CheckUserIfAdmin::class,
```

web.php

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['CheckAdmin']], function () {
    Route::get('/admin', [
        'uses' => 'AdminController@index',
        'as' => 'adminpage'
    ]);
});
```

my Middleware:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class CheckUserIfAdmin
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if(Session::has('ad_id') === false):
            return redirect()->route('admin.login');
        endif;


        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any error?

Comment: @GovindSamrow no it does nothing as i said

Comment: What do you mean by it does nothing? Isn't the middleware being executed? If you're not sure try and put something like `dd(1);` as first line in the `handle()` method to see if that method is being executed.

Comment: try to `dd($request);` at the top of `handle` method in middleware.

Comment: I tried dd($request) and still nothing

Comment: just comment out  your 

'CheckAdmin' => [
    \App\Http\Middleware\CheckUserIfAdmin::class,
], in Kernel.php/middlewareGroups and check

Answer (score 0):

There is syntax error in middleware remove `endif;` :

```
class CheckUserIfAdmin
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if(Session::has('ad_id') === false):
            return redirect()->route('admin.login');

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Comment: Still nothing i tried every possible solutions, but it doesn't work.